# Prove that the set of injective linear transformations is an open set.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, multivariable-calculus

Prove that the set of injective linear transformations from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$ is an open set. Using the fact that a Linear transformation is injective if and only if there is $\alpha>0$ such that $||T(x)||\geq \alpha||x||$ for all $x$. 
And the fact that if $A$ is the associate matrix then $||A||^2=\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}^2$ (Frobenius norm).

Please helpme with this problem. I'm really stuck. I dont know what exactly is what i have to prove.

Comment: You need to show that if $A$ is an injective transformation, then for $B$ close to $A$ (that is, $||A-B|| <\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon$), $B$ is also injective.

Comment: Further hint : If $\|I-T\| = \alpha < 1$, show that $T$ is injective (here $I$ denotes the natural inclusion $\mathbb{R}^n \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$)

Comment: In the two cases i'm really stuck. In the second case the operator is the identity operator ($n\times n$) wich is not $n\times m$ so how can i do $||I-T||$?? Please help me!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First an easy approach. Linear maps $L:{\mathbb R}^n\to{\mathbb R}^m$ can be seen as $n\times m$ real matrices $M$. Then injective linear maps correspond to rank $n$ matrices, that is, maximum rank matrices. Hence one has the open condition that *some $n\times n$ minor of $M$ is not zero*. If one insists on the norm condition, one rewrites it as *there is $\alpha$ such that*
$$
\left\|T\big(\tfrac{x}{\|x\|}\big)\right\|\ge\alpha>0.
$$ 
Hence $T$ is injective if and only if its minimum $\lambda$ in the (compact) unit sphere is $>0$. If $T_1$ is closer than, say, $\lambda/2$ to $T$, then $T_1$ cannot vanish on that sphere. Whether we use one or another norm is of no consequence, as all norms on an affine space are equivalent.

Answer (score 5):

There is a very simple way to do, not using the way that is suggested: the set of linear maps $\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$ is bijective to set of $n\times m$ matrices and the map to the set of $n\times n$ minors is continuous (given by polynomials), so the preimage of $0$ is closed, hence its complement is open. This complement being exactly the set of injective maps you are done.